# How to filter one ForeignKey field based on another ForeignKey field in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, filter, admin

I am trying to enter data in User model in django admin panel. I want to be able to filter the cities in the django admin panel when I select a country. The following is my code. I think I have to write some stuff in the admin.py file, but I have no clue where to start

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.ForeignKey('Country')
    city = models.ForeignKey('City')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Country(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.country

class City(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.ForeignKey('Country')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.city
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin

from third.models import User, Country, City

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(City)
admin.site.register(Country)
admin.site.register(User)
```

Comment: If you mean that the dropdown choices for city should update as you select a user's country, Django doesn't do this out of the box - it's a common request. I wrote my own Javascript last time I had to do it, but I've also seen this package commonly recommended: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-smart-selects/1.0.9 I haven't worked with it myself.

Comment: I have not been able to make it work! :-/